# Как отправить HTML файл через pyTelegramBot на python?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

У меня есть заранее сохраненный html файл. В ответ /start бот должен отправить этот файл, но выдает ошибку " Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: file must be non-empty"

```
            html = open("График.html", 'rb')
            bot.send_document(message.chat.id, html)
            html.close
```

Также попробовал отправить обычный txt файл, та же ошибка, но фото через bot.send_photo() исправно отправляет.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так отправился файл:

```
bot.send_document(message.chat.id, open(r'График.html', 'rb'))
```